# ISAPI Rewrite 3 rule for redirectling http to https for a particular site

Tags: iis-6, https, isapi-rewrite

I have multiple sites on a single IIS 6 server running ISAPI Rewrite 3 (free addition).

I need to redirect just one of the sites to https if the request comes in as http.

Example: I need `http://bar.foo.com` to redirect to `https://bar.foo.com`. I don't want this redirect to affect `http://www.foo.com` or `http://foo.com` or `http://meh.foo.com`.

What is the redirect syntax for this problem?

I found http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/examples.htm which shows how to redirect all requests to https.

Answer (score 1):

The rules should look like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^bar\.foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .? https://bar.foo.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an easy thing to do

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule http://bar.foo.com https://bar.foo.com [NC]
```